# How do you copy files from a remote server to a local folder in emacs using dired/tramp?

Tags: emacs, tramp

When I use tramp to open a remote directory (say C-x C-f /ssh:user@example:/somedirectory), it opens up a dired buffer for that remote directory. The problem is that I want to copy directories and or files from the remote server to my local machine. I've tried a few syntaxes like marking all the directory or files, pressing 'C', and specifying local:/somelocaldir or just /somelocaldir, but at best the files get copied onto a file somewhere on the remote server.

Is there a way to copy files from a remote (tramp) dired buffer to a local dir? I've only been using emacs 6 months, so if there's a completely different approach that is better and still lets me use emacs (preferably w/ dired), that would be great.

Just to clarify, I'm not interested in viewing, editing, listing, etc. remote files. I just want to copy files from a remote server to my local machine, with the same effect you'd get if you'd used scp or scp -r. I'm just hoping I can do this w/o having to drop out of emacs or even use the eshell (but I'll probably just do that until I get an answer here).

Comment: In most of the installations I've seen, `C-x C-f /user@somehost:/somedir` is sufficient since `scp` is the default exchange method.  Try it and see.  Maybe you can save a few key bumps.

Comment: That just opens a dired buffer. It doesn't actually copy the dir over like "scp -r user@somehost:/somedir ." would do.

Comment: I'm understanding your question more clearly now. The question title had me thinking you wanted to copy files directly from `dired`. I use `ansi-term` for commands like that if I don't want to leave emacs.  Emacs was built for customization.  I'm sure you'll get an answer with a lisp snippet at some point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way. This works for me on emacs 23.

In dired mode, navigate to the file you'd like to copy.

1. Press <kbd>M</kbd> to mark the file.
2. Do an `M-x dired-do-copy` and you'll be prompted for a location in the mini-buffer.
3. Edit the location to the local location you'd like to copy to and smack enter.

Done.